# Spring 3: Content Negotiation

Tags: spring-3, restful-architecture

I have a REST endpoint which currently returns JSON output. I would like to modify the same endpoint to return plain text output, basically differentiate between generating `application/json` and `text/plain` `Accept` headers. Here's my current configuration -

**servlet.xml:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="text" value="text/plain" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonView"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonView"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="disableCaching" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

**REST endpoint:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/emps", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmpsList() throws VMException {
    final List<Employee> eList = getAllEmployees();
    return eList;
}
```

I tried modifying produces to `{"application/json", "text/plain"}`. T read through some online stuff, and since I am returning a bean, I need to use `HttpMessageConverter` to return `text/plain` output. I was able to get this work by writing two methods, one returning `application/json` output and other returning `text/plain` output. Is it even possible to combine this into single method implementation, or importantly, return result based on requested output format, i.e. `json` or `text`.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Update:** Attaching image of the the postman client plugin.

Image 1:
[image: Image1]
Image 2:
[image: Image2]

Comment: What actually happens when you make your changes? No change at all? A 405 or 406?

Comment: Yes, I get 406. Thanks @Vidya.

Comment: Can you show examples of what your `Accept` header looks like in your requests?

Comment: @Vidya, I have updated the question with information (screenshots). Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

Comment: It is a little hard to read, but it looks like you have no `Accept` header in your first request.

Comment: @Vidya, the first request does not have `Accept` header, the output returned is in json format. The second has `Accept` header and I expect a text output. However, I get a `406`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have this:

```
<property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
```

In fact, you don't want to ignore the `Accept` header. Remove that and see what happens.

Also, the `mediaTypes` are only relevant if you are seeking recources by extension/format, which doesn't seem to be the case here.